# Logstash / Kibana : Adding new field to existing index in Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana

Currently I have the following index template used for filtering firewall logs:

```
GET /_template/my_logstash

{
  "my_logstash" : {
    "order" : 1000,
    "index_patterns" : [
      "filebeat-*",
      "firewall-*",
      "syslog-*",
    ],
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "whitespace_lowercase" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer" : "whitespace"
            },
            "keyword_lowercase" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "mapping" : {
          "total_fields" : {
            "limit" : "3000"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "dynamic" : "true",
        "properties" : {
          "bytes" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "bytes_in" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "bytes_out" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "dest_port" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "src_port" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "dest_translated_ip" : {
            "type" : "ip"
          },
          "src_translated_ip" : {
            "type" : "ip"
          },
          "dest_ip" : {
            "type" : "ip"
          },
          "src_ip" : {
            "type" : "ip"
          },
          "host" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "whitespace_lowercase",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "logsource" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "whitespace_lowercase",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "program" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "whitespace_lowercase",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "source" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "keyword_lowercase",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "sourcetype" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "whitespace_lowercase",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "username" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "whitespace_lowercase",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "geoip" : {
            "properties" : {
              "ip" : {
                "type" : "ip"
              },
              "location" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
              },
              "latitude" : {
                "type" : "half_float"
              },
              "longitude" : {
                "type" : "half_float"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases" : { }
  }
}
```

I want to add the following fields into `mappings/doc`:

```
     "domain": {
          "type": "text",
          }

     "threat_contenttype": {
          "type": "text",
          }
```

I would like to do this via Kibana's console. By reading the logtash doco I think it might be like this :

```
PUT /_template/my_logstash/_mapping
     "domain": {
          "type": "text",
          }

     "threat_contenttype": {
          "type": "text",
          }
```

Is this correct? I'm not sure if it is and too scared to run it incase it corrupts my current index.
I dont want to add the fields to the current data - I just want to use the new fields for some new firewall devices that will be sending logs to logstash.

Appreciate your thoughts,

J

Answer (score 0):

Any mapping template that you update will only be used for creation of new Index and does not affect data that is already indexed.

Elastic supports dynamic mapping so when you index new data with additional fields they would be automatically added. But yes for specific reasons you might want to control the mapping.

You might need to take more care when changing the type of an already index field. Have a look at below link.

[Elastic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)